# the slider do not responce

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to use the slider to change the figures, but it is no use. I think maybe the problem is in the Callback part. but i have no idea how to do it.

```
month = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
tilts = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
data = [0.1,0.2,0.3,1,2,3,11,12,13,21,22,24]
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':month,'tilt':tilts,'data'=data})

df_default = df[df['tilt']==1]

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': df_default.month.tolist(), 
    'y': df_default.data.tolist(), 
})

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var tilt = slider.value;
    var x = data['x']
    var y = data['y']
    'x'        = df[df['tilt']==tilt].month.tolist();
    'y'        = df[df['tilt']==tilt].data;
    plot.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, line_width=3, 
line_alpha=0.6, 
         );
    source.change.emit();
""")

slider = Slider(start=1, end=4, step=1, value=1, title='tilt')
slider.js_on_change('value',callback)

layout = row(
    plot,
    column(slider)
)

output_file("slider.html", title="slider.py example")

show(layout)
```

it can show , but apparently, the callback is not working

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this code, one of them is that these lines are nonsensical:

```
'x'        = df[df['tilt']==tilt].month.tolist();
'y'        = df[df['tilt']==tilt].data;
```

These are trying to assign values to string constants, which is invalid JavaScript. However, a bigger issue is that you are trying to use Pandas DataFrames in a `CustomJS` callback, and this can never work. Pandas DataFrames are a Python object, they do not exist inside browsers. To run real Python code, e.g. use Pandas DataFrames, you will have to [create and run a Bokeh Server application](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html).